# Numeric evaluation of a matrix product integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerical-integration, numerics, products

Working on a problem in quantum mechanics, I rediscovered a notion of a [product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_geometric_integral), which I was not familiar with before. In a simple case, when the integrand is a real-valued scalar function, then by taking a logarithm of it, the product integral can be in a straightforward way reduced to the regular integral that can be evaluated in *Mathematica* using `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`. The problem apparently becomes more complicated if the integrand is a matrix function. In particular, I am interested in a matrix product integral of the form:
$$\prod_0^1\exp\!\left(\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 f(x)  & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]\right)^{\!dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0^+} \left(\,\prod _{x=0,\,\Delta x,\,2\Delta x,\,\dots}^1 \exp\left(\Delta x\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 f(x)  & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]\right)\right),$$
where $\prod$ denotes the [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product) ([`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html)), $\exp(\cdot)$ denotes the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) ([`MatrixExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixExp.html)), and $f(x)$ is a real-valued, piecewise-smooth function (a particular form of that function depends on the problem we are trying to solve). The notation on the left is borrowed from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_geometric_integral); as usual, we write $dx$ to hint at an infinitesimal $\Delta x$.

As far as I can see, this kind of integrals is not directly supported by *Mathematica*. Symbolic evaluation of such integrals seems a difficult problem even for very simple functions $f(x)$ — I could not find any developed theory for that. For now, I would like to find a way to evaluate matrix product integrals numerically to arbitrary precision. Could you suggest a way to do it?

---

*Note:* The matrix exponent from the product can be evaluated as follows:
$$\small\exp\left(\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 f(x)  & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]\right)^{\!h}=\exp\left(h\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -1 \\
 f(x)  & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]\right)=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos \left(h\sqrt{f(x)}\right) & -h\operatorname{sinc} \left(h\sqrt{f(x)}\right) \\
 \sqrt{f(x)} \sin \left(h\sqrt{f(x)}\right) & \cos \left(h \sqrt{f(x)}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
*Note:* Originally I posted a matrix that had $1$ rather than $-1$ in its top-right corner. Now I’ve fixed this error, and the expression above now correctly contains trigonometric rather than hyperbolic functions.

---

*Update*: I found a closed form solution for a quadratic polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$; notation $D_\nu(z)$ stands for [`ParabolicCylinderD`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParabolicCylinderD.html).
[image: Closed form]
([see source](https://gist.github.com/VladimirReshetnikov/31f64e69da74cec1c0aed4a4761b1d22))

Comment: My related question at Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4329847/19661

Comment: For this example, why not use ∏g = exp(∫ log g), so that ∏exp(M) = exp(∫ log exp M) = exp(∫ M)?

Comment: @evan, because the matrix (dot) products complicate matters, as you might see from `Array[x, {2, 2}] . Array[y, {2, 2}]`; now imagine an entire (in fact infinite!) bunch of them.

Comment: Shouldn't that be handled by the fact that we can use matrix exps and logs?  Or is the formalism using a mixed meaning of exp, log, etc.?

Comment: @evan, looking at e.g. `MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {f[x1], 0}}] . MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {f[x2], 0}}] . MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {f[x3], 0}}] // Simplify` I don't see any easily exploitable structure, but you might see things differently...

Comment: @evanb It is not possible to reduce this matrix product to a sum simply by taking the logarithm because the matrix factors in the product do not commute in general. The correct result can be obtained in form of an infinite series using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula, which is quite complicated even when there are just two factors in the matrix product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula

Comment: Well, this is the $T$-exponent, if I see it right. Indeed, well known in physics. It describes a time-evolution operator. A practical method is to write a differential equation for it.

Comment: @yarchik I am not able to google anything useful about “T-exponent”. Could you please provide some references? Indeed, this matrix product integral can be seen as a solution to a differential equation.

Comment: You can look in Mahan, Many-particle physics, Sec. 2.1.C (978-0-306-46338-9), or in Stefanucci and van Leeuwen Nonequilibrium Many-Body Theory of Quantum Systems: A Modern Introduction Sec. 3.2 (978-1-139-02397-9).

Comment: Your closed form for the quadratic looks very imposing. Have you also tried looking at the linear case? (It's not clear to me that one can readily derive the linear case from your expression, even if you let $a\to 0$.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a little on the exploratory/speculative side, so *caveat emptor*.

Letting $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, if we try three different Riemann-like discretizations:

```
(* left *)
lSeq = With[{prec = 35}, 
            Table[Apply[Dot, MapThread[Function[{h, x}, MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {Log[1 + x], 0}}]],
                                       Through[{Differences, Most}[N[Subdivide[n], prec]]]]],
                  {n, LinearRecurrence[{0, 2}, {8, 12}, 14]}]];

(* right *)
rSeq = With[{prec = 35}, 
            Table[Apply[Dot, MapThread[Function[{h, x}, MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {Log[1 + x], 0}}]],
                                       Through[{Differences, Rest}[N[Subdivide[n], prec]]]]],
                  {n, LinearRecurrence[{0, 2}, {8, 12}, 14]}]];

(* midpoint *)
mSeq = With[{prec = 35}, 
            Table[Apply[Dot, MapThread[Function[{h, x}, MatrixExp[h {{0, 1}, {Log[1 + x], 0}}]], 
                                       Through[{Differences,
                                                MovingAverage[#, 2] &}[N[Subdivide[n], prec]]]]],
                  {n, LinearRecurrence[{0, 2}, {8, 12}, 14]}]]
```

(where I have used the so-called ["Bulirsch sequence"](https://oeis.org/A029744) $2,3,4,6,8,12,\dots$ with high-precision evaluation), and then feed the results to [`` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834), I get the following results:

```
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[lSeq, Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "Degree" -> 2}]
   {{1.258267041020026417604, 1.06692480900025473528},
    {0.40712785463903170298, 1.139960566770598057424}}

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[rSeq, Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "Degree" -> 2}]
   {{1.258267041014204419775, 1.066924811507401634993},
    {0.40712785465310075194, 1.139960566387343039431}}

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[mSeq, Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "Degree" -> 2}]
   {{1.25826704102519941889787971, 1.06692481134707652125411183},
    {0.40712785448828023753731087, 1.13996056685658832633988270}}

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[(lSeq + rSeq)/2, Method -> {"WynnEpsilon", "Degree" -> 2}]
   {{1.25826704102519941643151917, 1.06692481134707650233505942},
    {0.407127854488280241496255464, 1.13996056685658832978970988}}
```

which seem to point to an answer that is approximately `{{1.2582670410, 1.0669248}, {0.407127854, 1.139960566}}`. Note that `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[] `` uses an extrapolation method that is intended for *scalar* sequences, and one might get better results if one uses methods specially adapted for matrix sequences (e.g. [this one](https://doi.org/10.13001/1081-3810.3925)). One could also play around with the discretization used; I chose the Bulirsch sequence since the exponential growth is not as terrible as the sequence $2,4,8,16,\dots$ (sometimes referred to as the "Romberg sequence" in these contexts).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried a similar approach with `NSequenceLimit`, but the convergence is painfully slow (but the result seems to agree with the one obtained by solving the whole problem numerically rather than symbolically, using `NDSolve`).

Comment: @Vladimir, yes, I expected this kind of discretization to have relatively slow convergence even after acceleration. You mention in a comment that you are considering linear and quadratic $f(x)$; are these the particular cases you are interested in, or are there others?

Comment: I am mostly interested in polynomials because they can readily be used to approximate other smooth functions.

Comment: That makes sense. Even if we only have closed form results for the linear case, it would be very useful to build approximations from it.

Comment: I got much better convergence by using powers of $2$ to subdivide the interval.

Comment: I've added a closed form for quadratic polynomials to my question above. It is pretty heavy.